# Return to the caller state?

Tags: c#, state-machine, stateless-state-machine

I am using C#'s stateless state-machine, but I've had this issue in the past with other state-machine implementation. The question is mostly theoretical, though I can add some dummy code if asked for.

I have a situation which I am quite unsure how to solve. Lets say you have 2 states (walk and run), and they both can transition to a 3rd state (jump). Once the 3rd state is done, I wish to go back to the caller state. In a way, I'd have to be able to influence the callee trigger, but this is only passed on to `OnEntry` and the likes, not the state itself.

Using `EntryFrom` doesn't seem to work, because there is no way to influence the "jump" state itself, only the `OnEntry` function.
Using `PermitDynamic` doesn't seem to work either, because once in the "jump" state, I have no idea where I came from.

I could have 2 jump states (jumpfromrun, jumpfromwalk) with a single `OnEntry` function, to minimize some duplicate code. This is what I currently use.

I could save the previous state in an external variable and pass that to my state update. I do not wish to do this (at all).

Is there a known technique or way to deal with this sort of problem? Having a shared state, that should transition back to the caller?
Thank you!

Comment: The only way to be in your "jump" state, yet remember how you got there, is if you encoded that information either in the state (have a walk jump and a run jump), or in different kind of storage (a stack of a push down automaton, an extra enum variable, etc.)

Comment: As stated in the question, that is currently what I use. But it is not a great solution as you get a ton of copy-paste code, and the only line that is different is the trigger call :/ Both states are completely identical.

Comment: Why is it so much copy pasted code?  You have to duplicate the on entry, the OnEntry, the OnExit, and Permits, but the 'jump' code itself could be extracted out into a function that's called by both jump types

Comment: Changing my major? What does that even mean. Anyhow, I have a vague memory working somewhere where they had a more elegant solution to this problem. But I can't recall exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From reading the docs, it seems like this is a pretty good usecase for substates.

You can have a jump state:

```
stateMachine.Configure(State.Jumping)
    .OnEntry(() => StartJump())
    .OnExit(() => EndJump());
```

and two jump sub-states. One for walking, one for running:

```
stateMachine.Configure(State.WalkJumping)
    .SubstateOf(State.Jumping)
    .Permit(Trigger.DoneJumping, State.Walking);

stateMachine.Configure(State.RunJumping)
    .SubstateOf(State.Jumping)
    .Permit(Trigger.DoneJumping, State.Running);
```

Then you make walk and run route to WalkJumping and RunJumping, respectively.

```
stateMachine.Configure(State.Walking)
    .OnEntry(() => StartWalking())
    .OnExit(() => EndWalking());
    .Permit(Trigger.Jump, State.WalkJumping);


stateMachine.Configure(State.Running)
    .OnEntry(() => StartRunning())
    .OnExit(() => EndRunning());
    .Permit(Trigger.Jump, State.RunJumping);
```

Using substrates like this, as opposed to just regular states, has the added benefit that the `State.Jumping` can define the same `OnEntry` and `OnExit` that will be inherited by both `WalkJumping` and `EndJumping`.

Additionally, it gives you an easier way to check if you're in the middle of a jump. Instead of:

```
var state = stateMachine.state;
var isJumping = state == State.WalkJumping || state == RunJumping;
```

You can simply do:

```
var isJumping = stateMachine.IsInState(State.Jumping);
```

Which will properly consider all substates, which are currently `WalkJumping` and `RunJumping`. But if you add a new jump substate in the future, e.g. `DoubleJumping`, then the `isJumping` predicate will automatically cover that case too, without needing to remember to fix it.

Comment: This is the sort of thing I am looking for, thank you! Now, with substates, the parent "update" will be called as well. So I'm thinking you may be able to share both `OnEntry` and `TheUpdate`. You could probably just modify the exit points, using `PermitDynamic`, `PermitDynamicIf` or `OnEntryFrom` , so basically you end up with just 2 different exits. I will play around with this idea later today, but this is certainly an elegant and modelled solution.